# Custom ImageView with a progressBar as default image

Tags: android, imageview

In my application I have a `listView` Which uses **LazyLoading** to display images.

But until the actual image is downloaded and displayed, I want the `ImageView` to show a loading animation instead of some default Image.

I thought of creating a custom `imageView` which has a default image as a `ListDrawable` which looks like an animation. But is there any easier/common way to achieve this?

Thank You.

Comment: If you have time then try this make a transparent activity and then use a gif image of loading in it ,search on google you will find a way to load gif image in android :)

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, just use [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Answer (score 0):

Have a progressbar in each list item. Whenever you image gets downloaded, hide this progressbar[ set visibility GONE]. Your xml should look something

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgToBeSet"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/img_cont_desc_common" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/imgProgress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textMsg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgToBeSet"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="@string/msg_download_failed" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly common problem and could be solved by using one of the available libraries out there. When I needed something similar the libraries felt a little heavy weight.

A very simple solution is to create your ImageView with a default loading spinner. Now you have a ListView full of spinners. Next create a new AsyncTask class which takes a URL and returns a Bitmap. When the Async task completes assign the result to your ImageView using `myImageView.setImageBitmap(...);`. E.g. (no sensible error checking, etc)

```
public class MyLazyBitmapLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private ImageView imageView;

    public MylazyBitmapLoader(final ImageView imageView) {
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap result = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            result = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
        ...
        }
        return result;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        //handle null
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

This can easily be extended to include other features such as caching, other resource loading, etc